# X11 virtual output with Nvidia card (and amd processor)

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, x11-forwarding, xrandr, x11vnc

I have a Nvidia card and I'm trying to add a virtual screen, but no way to get this working

my xrand says that VIRTUAL output doesnt exists

```
root@workstation:/home/awill# xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1024x768
xrandr: cannot find output "VIRTUAL1"
```

I like to add a virtual output in X11, I have a NVidia 1030 and a AMD Ryzen 5  cpu

how can i do that? My xrandr output:

```
root@workstation:/home/awill# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2726 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1920x1080     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1360x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1360x768      60.02*+
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.97    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.95    59.94    59.93
```